Does the QCD effective force go to zero at high energies?
Admittedly, I'm not overly familiar with the nature of QCD experimental evidence but from what I gather it's pretty well established that experimentally quarks behave like free particles at high energies or low distances. Asymptotic freedom is often mentioned as helping to explain why quarks behave like free particles at high energy or small distances. But asymptotic freedom only says that the coupling constant goes to zero. What I'm interested in, is whether the whole force -- when you take into account the coupling constant and the functional form of the potential/force -- goes to zero. So to be more precise, we know from renormalization group methods that QCD perturbation theory is valid at high energies and hence we can expand in powers of coupling constant at high energies. If we calculate the tree level diagram for a singlet quark anti-quark interaction we get: $$V(r) = -\frac{4}{3}\frac{g^2}{4\pi r}$$ we know that $g$ is actually $g(r)$ i.e. it's a function of $r$. Now if experimental evidence implies that quarks are essentially free at high energies wouldn't that imply that $$-V'(r) \to 0 \text{  as  } r \to 0 $$
And this would impose constraints on the functional form of $g$? I know we can perturbatively calculate $g(\mu)$ from RG methods, but im asking for spatial dependence.

Since $\beta(\mu)$ is $\beta(p^2)$ i think you can get the spatial dependece by fourier transforming the beta function
